# Can't import m4a files to Audacity

Tags: macos, audio, m4a

I have installed the latest version of `ffmpeg` (3.1.2) through homebrew, and I have gone to Preferences -> Libraries and located the `ffmpeg` library in Audacity (`/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/lib/libavutil.55.17.103.dylib`).

Nothing happens when I load an m4a. If I import it through ⌘ + I it says "FFmpeg not found".

Comment: Is ffmpeg in your path?  Type `which ffmpeg` and post the results

Comment: @Allan yes. `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`. I told me to locate `libavutil.55.17.103.dylib`.

Answer (score 1):

Audacity (as of v2.4.1) is not looking for `libavutil.*.dylib`, it needs `ffmpeg.*.dylib`. That is not installed by homebrew.

You will need to download `ffmpeg.*.dylib` by following the instructions at https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/installing_ffmpeg_for_mac.html

It should automatically install the ffmpeg library and configure the Audacity Preferences > Library to:

`/Library/Application Support/audacity/libs/ffmpeg.55.64bit.dylib`

Then you will be able to import m4a audio files.

Comment: So what is the relation between ffmpeg.*.dylib and FFmpeg (https://www.ffmpeg.org) ? When I compile FFmpeg, no ffmpeg.*.dylib is generated. How do I build ffmpeg.*.dylib from source?

Answer (score 1):

Per what @wisbucky said, you need to have it looking for the right version. Per the docs [here](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/installing_ffmpeg_for_mac.html) "have 64-bit Audacity-compatible FFmpeg 2.2.x or 2.3.x shared libraries" is the required version (released in 2014), and the latest version of ffmpeg presently supported on homebrew is 4.4.1.
The newer version is not compatible, however development to support it is in progress.

Regarding ffmpeg 4.x support, it was recently merged into master, but then reverted due to regression and licensing issues as you can read about [here](https://bugzilla.audacityteam.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2775), [here](https://github.com/audacity/audacity/pull/741) and [here](https://github.com/audacity/audacity/issues/853), which seem to have disappointingly stalled forward progress in May 2021 as there have been no further commits on that code and I don't see any open tickets related to this work elsewhere.